# Can someone explain how to get flops for full Newton method?

Tags: numerical-methods, asymptotics, newton-raphson, jacobian

So we are considering the full Newton method for nonlinear equations. The algorithm includes:

```
for k=0,1...until converges(suppose n)
compute -F(x_k)
compute Jacobian matrix of F(x_k)
solve Jacobian matrix*k=-F(x_k)
update x_k+1=x_k+k
```

I am given that the LU factorization is $n^3/3+O(n^2)$ (for some reason not $O(n^3)$. There are $n^2$ flops in Jacobian matrix. My question is the total number of flops then: $n^2+n^3/3+O(n^2)$?

Comment: What does "suppose $n$" mean? I think the letter $n$ is being used for two different things in your question.

Comment: its a Newtons convergence rate in $n$ dimensions

Comment: For how many iterations does the algorithm run?

Comment: n iterations since it converges to n

Answer (score 1):

You are using $n$
as both the size of the matrix
and the number of iterations.
To me,
this does not make sense.

The number of iterations
definitely depends
on how close
the initial approximation
is to the actual result.

You are correct in that
the number of flops
per iteration
is
$n^3/3+O(n^2)$
for "solve Jacobian matrix*k=-F(x_k)"
and the number of flops
for the other steps
is at least $O(n^2)$
and may be more
depending on the complexity
of computing
F(x_k)
and its Jacobian.

If $m$ is the number of iterations,
which can not
be computed in advance,
the total number of flops
would be
$mn^3/3+O(mn^2)$.

I don't think that
you can say anything more.